# Перевод из 10-ой системы в 5-ую. C++

Tags: c++

Есть ли простой способ перевода из 10-ой в 5-ую систему счисления на c++?

Comment: Смотря как трактовать термин "простой" :)

Comment: Функция itoa() конвертирует целое число num в строчный эквивалент и помещает результат в строку, на которую указывает параметр str. Основание системы счисления для записи выходной строки определено параметром radix, который может принимать значения в интервале от 2 до 36.

Comment: itoa(atoi(str), buffer, 5) - наверное как-то так?

Answer (score 0):

Был у меня где-то код, который переводил из десятичной в любую (вплоть до 36 - ичной, а дальше просто кончился латинский алфавит), но увы, я его не найду. Суть любого перевода простая: делите на основание СС (в вашем случае - на 5) , а остаток от деления добавляете к строке-ответу ( `string ans; ans += chislo % 5`), и так пока число / 5 != 0.